# Numpy - module has no attribute 'arrange'

Tags: python, numpy

Seems like an incredibly basic error, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version of Numpy (1.9) and that didn't seem to solve my issue. I am getting the following error when trying to use the arrange function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "names.py", line 37, in <module>
    top1000.index = np.arrange(len(top1000))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arrange'
```

Printing the version confirms that it is indeed 1.9. I've not been able to come across anyone else reporting this specific issue. I've also tried this on two separate Macs and still get the same exact error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print np.__version__

grouped = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])
top1000 = grouped.apply(get_top1000)
top1000.index = np.arrange(len(top1000))
```

Comment: Do you mean [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)? There is no NumPy function named `arrange`.

Comment: Damnit...lol I need more coffee. Thanks dude!

Comment: It happens to all of us!

Comment: Same happened with writing linespace instead of linspace.

Comment: it is not np,arrange but it should be np.arange. no double r.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason why NumPy spells "arrange" as "arange"? It doesn't seem to be a correct American English spelling of the word. Maybe there's a historical reason, or maybe it's a regional spelling (i.e., UK)?

Comment: @ClintLaskowski I assume it should be read as "a range" instead of a misspelled "arrange"

Comment: @YoungFrog Very true. One who doesn't yet understand what this function does can easily make that mistake. Example, `np.arange(6)` yeilds `[0 1 2 3 4 5]`

Comment: LOL thanks @ely -- i also need more coffee.

Answer (score 71):

You should try `numpy.arange()` instead, if that is what you meant?

Comment: arange is spelled with only one 'r', so in the example given it should be np.arange().
To me this answer isn't super clear because it changes np to numpy, but doesn't say anything about the misspelling

Comment: I think its not arranging something, rather represents a RANGE

Comment: Not sure why this is off topic. It just saved my behind and has 39k views. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Agree.  This is not off topic.  the problem is that there is a common misspelling of a method.  The a in front of range does not make sense to me, and hence causes the confusion with arrange.

Comment: It's 2023. I still received a misspelling notebook...